# Possible to reference iPhone Application project from iOS Unit Tests project?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nunit, xamarin-studio

I am able to reference an Android Application project from an Android Unit Test project. (So that I can write unit tests for my Android Application project.)

Similarly, I would like to reference an iPhone Application project from an iOS Unit Tests project (so that I can write unit tests for my iPhone application project). Is this possible?

If I open the "Edit References" window for my iOS Unit Tests project, the iPhone Application project is greyed out and not selectable. Any ideas?

Both projects have the SDK Version and Deployment Target specified as 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I got a response from a Xamarin support representative today saying that it's not possible to reference an iPhone Application project from an iOS Unit Tests project. I am told that the workaround is to extract the code to be tested to a library project and to test that instead.

I was also told that it's not possible to reference an Android Application project from an Android Unit Tests project. Quite strange then that I've been able to do this...